# Sparse Transaction in R

Tags: r, transactions, sparse-matrix, apriori

I'm working with POS data and I'm getting an error due to the size of my data being too big. I have 835,000 rows I'm trying to get into a transaction form to use the apriori algorithm from the arules package.

This is what I'm trying:

```
transactions = as(split(first2$Product_Desc,f=first2$Rtl_Id),"transactions")
```

It has this error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 45.7 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unique(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive, FALSE))) :
  Reached total allocation of 8103Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In unique(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive, FALSE))) :
  Reached total allocation of 8103Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In unique(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive, FALSE))) :
  Reached total allocation of 8103Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In unique(.Internal(unlist(lapply(x, levels), recursive, FALSE))) :
  Reached total allocation of 8103Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

How can I make this work?